# How to lists the maximum of counting with where syntax?

Tags: oracle, count, max, where-clause

For Oracle,

I have 2 tables; first is Store and another is Book whereas they are connected by store ID (PK FK).
I would like to lists the name of the store which has the highest numbers of books.
However, the result showed every store in orders but I just want the highest.

```
    SELECT STORE.STORE_NAME
    FROM STORE, BOOK
    WHERE STORE.STORE_ID=BOOK.BOOK_STOREID
    GROUP BY STORE.STORE_NAME
    ORDER BY COUNT(BOOK.BOOK_STOREID) DESC;
```

the result is

Store:
D
E
F
B
A
C

It should be only 'D'. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT STORE_NAME
FROM
(SELECT STORE.STORE_NAME
    FROM STORE, BOOK
    WHERE STORE.STORE_ID=BOOK.BOOK_STOREID
    GROUP BY STORE.STORE_NAME
    ORDER BY COUNT(BOOK.BOOK_STOREID) DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aa4e/1)

BTW, you can also use row_number() function

```
select STORE_NAME
from
(SELECT STORE.STORE_NAME, 
       row_number() over( order by COUNT(BOOK.BOOK_STOREID)desc) rn
    FROM STORE join BOOK on STORE.STORE_ID=BOOK.BOOK_STOREID
group by STORE.STORE_NAME)
where rn = 1;
```

---

**UPDATE** If you want to see all stores which have the max number of books you can use rank instead of row_number:

```
select STORE_NAME
from
(SELECT STORE.STORE_NAME, 
       rank() over( order by COUNT(BOOK.BOOK_STOREID)desc) rn
    FROM STORE join BOOK on STORE.STORE_ID=BOOK.BOOK_STOREID
group by STORE.STORE_NAME)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: The second one is pretty good while short and sweet. Thank you so much.

Comment: From this questions, I've found that if some stores have the same numbers of books which are the maximum. The results wouldn't show both of them, but will show only one with alphabet orders. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Thank you, now I'm gonna go fix another one that you have answered me yesterday (Inception situations). It seems like it has the same problem there. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another formulation:

```
with store_counts as (
  select store_name,
         count(*) books
    from store join book on store_id=book_storeid
group by store_name)
select *
from   store_counts
where  books = (
         select max(books)
         from store_counts)
```